# INT_4_BYTES macro definition

Tags: c

is the macro INT_4_BYTES is a standard one and defined in one of the .h files that come with the compiler?

Same question regarding the int32 typedef.

Comment: Which compiler?  Which header file? Every compiler comes with its own header files....

Comment: `INT_4_BYTES` is not a standard macro. And `int32` is not part of the standard library either. You are going to need to be more precise.

Comment: Just use google as the oracle, query for "int_4_bytes" and "c" (with quotes).  Getting 43 search results with your question on top tells you that it is *not* anything standard.  The first hit for "int32" and "c" tells you want you want to know about your 2nd question.

Comment: Tnx @DavidHeffernan !

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about INT_4_BYTES or int32 (which do not look standard at all, they might be specific to some compiler or library); if you're looking for standard types for 32-bit integers, you might want to `#include <stdint.h>` and use the `int32_t` (singed) and `uint32_t` (unsigned) types.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an IDE that you are coding in, you may be able to right click on the element and traverse to the definition.  Then see where it is defined.

Visual Studio: Right Click -> "Go To Definition (F12)"
Eclipse: Right Click -> "Open Declaration (F3)"